# Display the contents of a Windows File Server

Tags: sharepoint-online, explorer-view, windows, file-server

I am currently trying to set up SharePoint for my company. I have been advised that I am not allowed to put proprietary information on SharePoint.

I would like to be able to  access and manage files stored on the local server from SharePoint Online 2013. Without the files being stored in SharePoint. The files are stored on a Windows server.

I have seen SharePoint display the contents of the Windows server if that individual has been granted access to the server. If the individual does not have access the window remains blank. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might have been using a page viewer web part pointed to a network share. This puts an explorer like view on a SharePoint page that allows you to interact with files located on a file share as if it were in SharePoint but not actually residing there.

Answer (score 0):

System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files

This page will display a list of all open files accessed on that server in a Windows Server environment. Inside, you'll see the directory path of the file being accessed, the user's username, the file's status, and the number of locks on the file.